# false advertising on a 3rd party platform

Tags: internet, business

On LendingTree.com I was searching for cars on sale in my area, and I saw a 2015 Avalon advertised for $8000. It said for more information call the dealership.  I called the dealership and they apologized and said it's a mistake and that same car is $26,000. They also said it's not the first time, and that car and wrong price must have slipped through the cracks.

I then called LendingTree.com and they said that the dealership directly provides all cars and their prices.

2 days later I went to the LendingTree.com and since my phone call to the dealership they (the dealership) have corrected their mistake and now the Avalon is listed properly as $26,000.

My question is can I hold the dealership or anybody liable for this mistake?  I mean it was nationally advertised for $8000!

Answer (score 2):

People are not liable for mistakes. They *may* be liable for mistakes that damage other people.

By advertising the incorrect price, except for the disappointment you felt when you couldn't buy a $26,000 car for $8,000, no one suffered any damage.

You say advertised nationally but you don't tell us what nation you are talking about. If this was Australia then the Australian Consumer Law would require the dealership to withdraw the car from sale until the price was corrected: they appear to have done this.